# Historically, has stock value gone up in relation to corporate tax cuts? To what extent?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing

Corporations (in the US) are getting significant tax cuts and I'm curious to know if this is just a move that makes companies happy to have extra money, or if it'll actually monetarily benefit shareholders. I've heard that corporations don't typically make major decisions based on this increased wealth because they can't rely on it not to be revoked by future administrations. So how will such cuts affect company stock value? To put it in a more answerable form: Historically, how has stock value changed in correlation to significant corporate tax cuts in the past? Or can any correlation be proven at all?

Comment: I see this as more related to economics than personal finance, so not on topic here.  (If you're asking whether you should buy buy buy... the answer is no, unless you're Jim Cramer.)

Comment: @Joe What about in regards to someone *else*'s finances? My purpose for asking was to learn if corporate tax cuts are personally beneficial to shareholders, or whether they really dont see much direct personal wealth gain.

Comment: Questions about economics, accounting, might have some bearing on personal finance as well, but they're not *directly* related.  Same thing.  The idea is we're a site for asking more of the 'how to' questions about personal finance; the big picture theoretical stuff isn't really our area.

Comment: Personally I see this as mainly a stock investing question so I wouldn't consider it offtopic here, although it certainly is also related to economics. The question could be reworded like: Can a major tax cut decision like the current one have any effects on stock returns, based on historical evidence?

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately not much data for this, because in the modern history the trend with the US and other governments has been to raise, not cut taxes.

Another problem is that the circumstances are always very different. For instance, you never had near zero interest rates and globally interconnected economy like now.

If we look at Reagan's tax cuts of 1981 and 1986, probably the only relevant and somehow comparable examples, the stock market had a great rally 1982-2000 following these, with some interruptions (such as the 1987 crash coming shortly after the second tax cut). However, the conditions were very different. The tax cuts came after a period of recessions and stock bear market lasting more than a decade. Today you have economic boom and stocks at all time highs. Interest rates in the early 1980's were very high, today they are extremely low. And you could find a number of other differences - such as technology, politics, demography. Or the size of US debt. Besides supporting business and economic activity, the tax cuts may put public finances under further pressure due to reduced tax revenue.

Furthermore, we should keep in mind that correlation does not automatically mean causation (tax cuts causing stocks to grow). I think Janet Yellen also mentioned this at the last week's press conference.

Last but not least, it is quite common for the markets to rise when something positive is anticipated, and when it finally comes, there is no further reaction (or even the market reacts in the opposite way), because everybody already knows and has traded on the news. This is not always the case, but often. This applies to the short term, in the long run the stocks are of course driven by fundamentals of the economy.

Comment: in the grand scheme of things, the tax "cut" is not much of a cut. The US Govt takes in $3 trillion/year, spends $4 trillion/year, and is cutting about $0.14 trillion in revenue. This is not changing the math; it's only rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic. We have a spending problem, not a tax problem.